# EPS to JPEG, poor quality result

Tags: c#, magick.net

I'm using [Magick.NET](https://github.com/dlemstra/Magick.NET/tree/master/Documentation) to export EPS file to JPEG using the following code:

```
MagickReadSettings settings = new MagickReadSettings();
settings.ColorSpace = ColorSpace.sRGB;
settings.Format = MagickFormat.Eps;

using (MagickImage _image = new MagickImage())
{
    _image.Read(image.Path, settings); //Loading the EPS
    _image.Resize(3000, 3000); //The max size will be 3000px
    _image.Density = new Density(300); //Setting DPI = 300
    _image.Write("teste.jpg"); //Saving the EPS
}
```

The result is so poor and I dont know why. There are someting to configure before use `_image.Write`? 
See the result by Photoshop exportation and Magick.NET exportation:

Photoshop(2167x2322 300dpi):

[image]

Magick.NET(2800x3000 300dpi):

[image]

Link of the EPS file: https://ufile.io/hhokl

Comment: Why do you expect a good quality when going from `2167x2322` to `2800x3000`? It's not even close to the same aspect ratio

Comment: `2167x2322` is just a example when i export by Photoshop, when I read the EPS file via C#, i'm able to resize to any value.

Comment: The original file is a .EPS dont have a size right?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto i edited the post with the EPS file.

Comment: That looks like you have JPEG compression artifiacts (and color space issues). What is the default JPEG compression settings for Magick.NET?

Comment: @NetMage the default is LosslessCompress

Comment: Guys i find the solution thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To have a great quality it's necessary to set the file configuration before load it through `MagickReadSettings`.

```
MagickReadSettings settings = new MagickReadSettings();
settings.ColorSpace = ColorSpace.sRGB;
settings.Format = MagickFormat.Eps;
settings.Compression = Compression.LosslessJPEG;
settings.Density = new Density(300);

using (MagickImage _image = new MagickImage())
{
    _image.Read(image.Path, settings);
    _image.Write("teste.jpg");
}
```

New result:
[image]

Comment: Very nice. Color space still seems an issue? (Background black not as deep?),

Comment: So ... I realized this after solving the problem of resolution, that's another problem: / cuz EPS file is not changing its color mode from CMYK to RGB

Comment: Just .AI files are changing the file color mode

Comment: Can you verify if your EPS file versus your AI file includes a color profile? You may need to specify a color profile for the conversion if not.